# How to generate date sequence between two dates in same column in R

Tags: r

I am struggling to generate a date sequence between two dates in same column using R script.

I have request id and sequence ID, Date and status.
[Input table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmeoe.jpg)

My requirement is to generate table like this. 
[desired output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmhtd.jpg)

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't a free coding service. Please review the [Help Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how to ask a good question for SO.

Comment: Please post your data as text, preferably using `dput` so we can see the original data types, not as an image.

Comment: @ Sean, Next time I will ensure to do as suggested. I have just started learning R. I worked out date sequence generation between two dates in same column, this bit was challenging, so I was looking for suggestion.  @ camille - Sure, will post data as text next time. Thank you both for you suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the `tidyverse` libraries. First set your date column to dates with `dmy` in the `lubridate` package.  Then you can use `tidyr` functions `complete` and `fill` to extend your datatable as shown.  `complete` has the option to fill in the gaps by day. `group_by` ReqID to do this for each of your individual identifiers.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df <- data_frame(ReqID = 100, ID_Seq = 1:3, Created = dmy("01/01/2018","10/01/2018","18/01/2018"), Status = c("Scheduled","In Execution", "Completed"))
df %>%
  group_by(ReqID) %>% 
  complete(Created = seq.Date(min(Created),max(Created), by = "day")) %>%
  fill(ReqID,ID_Seq,Status)

## A tibble: 18 x 4
#   Created    ReqID ID_Seq Status      
#   <date>     <dbl>  <int> <chr>       
# 1 2018-01-01   100      1 Scheduled   
# 2 2018-01-02   100      1 Scheduled   
# 3 2018-01-03   100      1 Scheduled   
# 4 2018-01-04   100      1 Scheduled   
# 5 2018-01-05   100      1 Scheduled   
# 6 2018-01-06   100      1 Scheduled   
# 7 2018-01-07   100      1 Scheduled   
# 8 2018-01-08   100      1 Scheduled   
# 9 2018-01-09   100      1 Scheduled   
#10 2018-01-10   100      2 In Execution
#11 2018-01-11   100      2 In Execution
#12 2018-01-12   100      2 In Execution
#13 2018-01-13   100      2 In Execution
#14 2018-01-14   100      2 In Execution
#15 2018-01-15   100      2 In Execution
#16 2018-01-16   100      2 In Execution
#17 2018-01-17   100      2 In Execution
#18 2018-01-18   100      3 Completed
```

Comment: Thank you Jasbner. I am beginner in R, will try these library and functions. I was trying do-while and was not getting anywhere. Thank you very much for your direction and time. This is indeed helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jasbner! I have installed dplyr and tidyr packages as suggested.
I am using 'mutate' to fix the date format.

## my csv file (file.csv) holds these data lines

ReqID   Seq Created         Status

100 1   01/01/2018  Scheduled

100 2   10/01/2018  Execution

100 3   15/01/2018  Hold

100 4   18/01/2018  Complete

101 1   10/01/2018  Scheduled

101 2   18/01/2018  Execution

101 3   20/01/2018  Complete

102 1   18/01/2018  Scheduled

102 2   22/01/2018  Execution

102 3   25/01/2018  Cancelled

103 1   01/02/2018  Scheduled

---

### # my final r script

mydata<-read.csv('file.csv') # Reading data from csv

myindf<-as.data.frame(mydata) # converting it into data frame

myoutdf <- myindf %>% mutate(Created = dmy(Created)) %>% group_by(ReqID) %>% complete(Created = seq.Date(min(Created),max(Created), by = "day")) %>% fill(ReqID,Seq,Status)

print(myoutdf, n = 38)  #print all 38 lines